# SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

SQL Server Management Studio is not connecting with the server name in client machine, but it is working fine with server IP address.

Comment: @marc_s: You shouldn't either.

Comment: Can you ping your SQL Server by machine name from your client?? Does `ping (machinename)` work?? If not: you have a DNS-/name resolution problem on the network level...

Answer (score 4):

This looks more a network related problem than a SQL problem. Check you network names, DNS, etc.